# dynamically created select controls not triggering events on keypress

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with some dynamically created select controls [below] they work when a user uses the mouse to change the control, but not on key events [tab to the control and use arrows to change the value] How should I change the jQuery so that keyboard event can be used to manipulate the select controls?

here is the jquery that fires when the mouse is used to change the control, but not when the keyboard is used:

```
$('#sub-budgets-container').on('change','.budget_type_id',function() {

      console.log('select changed')

      var option = $(this).val();
      var container = $(this).parent().parent().parent();

      $(container).find(".hidden_budget_type_id").val(option);   

    });
```

here is the jquery that clones the select control container:

```
$('#add-sub-budget').click(function(){

        console.log('button clicked');
        var newBudgetGroup = $('#budget-amounts').clone();
        newBudgetGroup.find('.budget_type_id').removeAttr('disabled');
        newBudgetGroup.find('.budget_type_id').attr('id', 'budget_type_id_control[]');
        newBudgetGroup.find('.budget_type_id').attr('name', 'budget_type_id_control[]');
        newBudgetGroup.find('#budget-id-select').removeClass('hidden');
        newBudgetGroup.find('.budget_amount').val('');
        newBudgetGroup.attr('id', 'sub-budget-amounts');
        //newBudgetGroup.find('.hidden_budget_type_id').remove();
```

newBudgetGroup.blur();
            newBudgetGroup.insertBefore('#sub-budgets');

```
    });
```

**UPDATE**

figured it out:

```
    $('#add-sub-budget').click(function(){

            console.log('button clicked');
            var newBudgetGroup = $('#budget-amounts').clone();
            newBudgetGroup.find('.budget_type_id').removeAttr('disabled');
            newBudgetGroup.find('.budget_type_id').attr('id', 'budget_type_id_control[]');
            newBudgetGroup.find('.budget_type_id').attr('name', 'budget_type_id_control[]');
            newBudgetGroup.find('#budget-id-select').removeClass('hidden');
            newBudgetGroup.find('.budget_amount').val('');
            newBudgetGroup.attr('id', 'sub-budget-amounts');
            //newBudgetGroup.find('.hidden_budget_type_id').remove();
newBudgetGroup.blur();
            newBudgetGroup.insertBefore('#sub-budgets');

        });
```

Comment: maybe try `selectmenuchange` instead of `change` .. if this is a jquery ui select menu?

Comment: sorry - does not work, not a ui select menu. from what I've been reading it looks like the keypress or onblur [or something] is not bound to the dom when the new select controls are created.

Comment: as it turns out this was pretty easy : newBudgetGroup.blur();